# Silverlight - Determine if a wma is protected by DRM

Tags: silverlight, drm, wma

Is there a way to determine if a wma file is DRM'd?  I'd like to be able to do this in a trusted, out of browser Silverlight 4 application so pinvoke isn't an option.  I supposed I could just try to play the file in a MediaElement but that doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check the MediaElement State during StateChanged event and you should be able to figure out if the video is DRMed or not.

There's a code sample @ "[Digital Rights Management (DRM) - Detecting DRM State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838192(VS.95).aspx#detecting_drm_state)".

Quick word of friendly advise, since you're obviously going to work with DRM in Silverlight and you're lacking basic knowledge how that works - read the whole article. It'll do you a world of good.

Answer (score 0):

Is file local or remote? For a local file you can read first N Kb of a file, parse ASF header and check if WMDRM headers are present.